# Is there a way to change icon size in a Mapbox map based on mobile vs desktop viewing?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I created a map in Mapbox studio and added it to my website. When viewed on desktop, the size of the icon points on the map are great. When I view on mobile, they're a bit too large. Is there a way to size the icons differently when viewing a map on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox-GL-JS doesn't itself provide support for desktop vs mobile. However:

If you're using Markers, you can give them responsive styling like anything else. For instance:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){
    .mapboxgl-marker {
        width: 20px;
    }
}
```

If you're using symbol layers, you would need to detect when the window size changes, and use that to set an appropriate `icon-size`.